# Variable on Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap application on every platform. Everything goes well except the declaring of variable. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var something = "Sth";
  document.addEventListener('deviceready',startsth(),false);
  function startsth(){document.write(something);}
    ....
</script>
```

When I try to check if there is internet, the application outputs "undefined". It works fine if I do not check the network. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. "undefined variable something" isn't very helpful. What's the console say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting the `deviceready` handler in a wrong way:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',startsth(),false);
                                                 ^------ REMOVE THIS PARENS
```

when you connect to `startsth()` you are using the return value of the `startsth` function, instead of a pointer to the function itself, which is just `startsth`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var something = "Sth";
  document.addEventListener('deviceready',startsth,false);
  function startsth(){document.write(something);}
    ....
</script>
```

You were calling the function `startsth` immediately with the parentheses afterwards, i.e. `startsth()`, rather than merely passing it as a function reference to be registered as a listener, to be called later upon the `deviceready` event.

**UPDATE:**

Other things to try:

Make sure you have the path for src="phonegap.js" correct.

Move the scripts to near the top of the document  so that you don't miss any events.

Switch the order of the scripts in case the event is being fired very quickly and you're missing it.

Don't use `document.write(...)` - it overrides the page contents if called after the DOM has loaded, resulting a mostly blank page.

Comment: Still not useful. I've tried for many times yet it did not seem to work.